# some of my https requests in Jmeter arbitrarlily switches to plain http but keeps the port on 443

Tags: https, jmeter

The request samplers are set up to use https and port 443. But sometimes JMeter sends a http request but keeps the port on 443, like http://example.com:443/?param=example

It should be 
https://example.com/?param=example on port 443

It works like 75% of the time. What would cause Jmeter to decide to go for http only on some threads?

Comment: Are you using the HTTP sampler? What do you have in the "Protocol" text box?

Comment: https and 443 in the Port Number box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing a HTTP Request Defaults config element. That config must have confused the rest of the script.

I also got the same tips from Blazemeter on Twitter, after I had solved it.